# How to make a WebView android app with mobile friendly website as URL?

Tags: android, url, android-studio, webview

As I know i have to use android studio for this.

But i am looking for someone who can tell step by step process to change what all codes to make that app a web view app with a test URL foo.com .

What i did till now :

1. I open Android Studio
2. Choose a blank activity

   Please let me know further steps that works

Please note that i am not looking to develop this on eclipse as new Android Studio is more preferable for me to work with

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` in your activity's onCreate method. You would then make an xml file in the layout folder containing the WebView. Those are the basics to get you started. You can look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) for examples and the documentation. There are also lots of tutorials online.